# session.gc_maxlifetime or session.cookie_lifetime not working

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies, session-timeout

[image]The user should stay logged a week in when closing the browser. But session killed.
Here is my code.

```
<?php
$lifetime = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
ini_set('session.use_cookies', 1);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 0);
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',$lifetime);
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', '1');
ini_set('session.gc_probability', '1');
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', $lifetime);
session_start([
    'cookie_lifetime' => $lifetime,
]);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `ini_set` within a script won't last when the script is finished. Why not edit this configuration in your php.ini?

Comment: To add, on why that is important here: _Other_ scripts you might have running, might also trigger the garbage collector that cleans up session data. And if those script do not use the _same_ settings, they might trigger the removal of a session earlier, than you intended.